# SharePoint 2010 PowerShell Getting List Column Object From Display Name Intermittently Gets Column

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get columns in a list from the display name, however this isn't always working.    Here is where I try to get the column, and check to see if it's null.  I've tried it on display names without and with spaces.  Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.  The display names haven't been changed.

```
                $column = $list.Fields[$columnName]
                if($column -ne $null)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since [SPFieldCollection.Item property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457291%28v=office.15%29.aspx) expects `DisplayName` to be passed, it should work properly, for example:

```
$field = $list.Fields["Created By"]
```

From another hand, [SPFieldCollection.GetField method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcollection.getfield%28v=office.15%29.aspx) returns the field with the specified internal, display, or static name from the collection

### How to return encoded Xml name via PowerShell

```
function EncodeName($name)
{
   $encodedName = [System.XML.XmlConvert]::EncodeName($name)
   return $encodedName 
}
```

Example: resolve field by Display Name

```
$fieldIntName = EncodeName("Post Category") #try to resolve field InternalName from DisplayName (works for fields created via UI)  
$field = $list.Fields.GetField($fieldIntName)  #get field by InternalName
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide Internal Names instead of Display Names for the fields.. Most importantly the space gets replaced with `_x0020_` in the Internal Name.. Following table shows the list of characters with their codes

```
Character    Internal Hex Code

    ~             _x007e_

    !             _x0021_

    @             _x0040_

    #             _x0023_

    $             _x0024_

    %             _x0025_

    ^             _x005e_

    &             _x0026_

    *             _x002a_

    (             _x0028_

    )             _x0029_

    _                _

    +             _x002b_

    -             _x002d_

    =             _x003d_

    {             _x007b_

    }             _x007d_

    :             _x003a_

    "             _x0022_

    |             _x007c_

    ;             _x003b_

    ‘             _x0027_

    \             _x005c_

    <             _x003c_

    >             _x003e_

    ?             _x003f_

    ,             _x002c_

    .            _x002e_

    /            _x002f_

    `            _x0060_

  [Space]        _x0020_
```

You can also run following Powershell command to get the list of Fields with Internal Names

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://sharepoint/sites/training/salestraining
$list = $web.Lists["Announcements"]
$list.fields | select Title, InternalName, StaticName | sort title | ft -AutoSize
```

References:

[SharePoint Internal Names](http://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2008/05/07/sharepoint-column-names-internal-name-mappings-for-non-alphabet/)
[SharePoint Finding Display and Internal Names](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2012/10/sharepointfinding-column-display-and.html)